# Show the charge in the angularjs front-end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, stripe-payments

I want to add a payment page in my mean-stack website. I am following https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/express.

The main difference is that I want to use angularjs. So I have created a `pay.html`:

```
<form action="/httpOnly/charge" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_AonyNpyBLlSWdLN7ZsUagG0h" 
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Stripe.com"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-zip-code="true">
  </script>
</form>
```

And the router:

```
router.post("/httpOnly/charge", (req, res) => {
    var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_CZnHvVa3ntbFSDSd57h5VB4A");

    let amount = 500;

    stripe.customers.create({
        email: req.body.stripeEmail,
        source: req.body.stripeToken
    })
    .then(customer =>
        stripe.charges.create({
            amount: amount,
            description: "Sample Charge",
            currency: "usd",
            customer: customer.id
    }))
    .then(charge => {
        console.log("charge: " + JSON.stringify(charge))
        ???
    })
})
```

As I don't want to use `pug`, I don't know how to send the result and show it in the front-end.

Could anyone help?

Comment: So, you just want to keep the `charge` variable around, or the object you are creating with `JSON.stringify` for later use?

Comment: I want to send `charge` to the front-end, and show it...

Comment: The best way to do this is to have a service component that handles the integration with the charge and saves the results.  https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4